# REST service as an application server for 2000+ client machines. Is it a good idea?

Tags: java, design, rest, spring

We will be building a system with the UI in javaFx that will be deployed to 2000+ machines (minimum is 2000, but it will be more - can reach 5000 machines).

For other reasons/limitations it must be installed on the machine, so we cannot do it with a web browser interface.

The 2000+ machines will be in different geographic location groups. In general the connection is good, but may not be so good on more remote locations.

Instead of accessing the database directly I am thinking about building a REST service cluster with Spring + Spring Boot + Spring Data (java).

The REST service would accept and return Json.

I think it is a good idea because:

- The service would act as a database connection pool (I think 2000+ connections on a database would cause problems);
- It is possible to have a database with log shipping to other read-only database to serve some queries;
- It would scale better as we can add more machines to run the REST services;
- It is possible to use HTTPS with compression for security and bandwidth saving reasons;
- It is possible to make some centralized changes on business entities without redeploying the 2000+ machines;
- It integrates better with other systems (just point it to the REST service).

Is it really a good idea?

Can you share some positive or negative experience?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's a sensible idea, especially since REST is designed with caching in mind.  You *may* consider using websockets to reduce the load from non-persistent client connections, but this depends on the pattern of usage of your API.  WebSocket begins to show its strengths when it's possible to multiplex a large number of small req/res transactions onto a persistent connections.  That said, it might be simpler to just scale out ...

Comment: Databases should never be accessible from the public internet and always be behind a firewall – therefore, shielding them through a REST API or similar is standard procedure. This also allows you to add other security features more easily, e.g. prevent users from editing data entries they are not authorized to see or edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open ended questions with lots of possible responses that depend on what you are trying to do. Nevertheless I'll add a few things as an answer, since a comment won't be large enough.

> The service would act as a database connection pool (I think 2000+ connections on a database would cause problems);

Yes, that's a good idea. You keep a smaller number of connections opened and you reuse them as requests arrive to the service. But you need to know how fast requests will be served and how much each request uses the 
database, otherwise a small pool can easily be depleted and other requests will get blocked while waiting for a database connection to be released.

Caching can help there, to return already fetched data (like I said, depends 
on what you are trying to do - if queries are unique you can't cache much).

Also note that the pool size will get multiplied by the number of services you put in place. A few services and you can use large database pool sizes; more services and you need to decrease the pool size, so that you have the same number of connections opened to the database, overall.

> It is possible to have a database with log shipping to other read-only database to serve some queries;

The database can easily become your bottleneck. Too many connections and/or too many queries and you can break it. At that point it doesn't matter that you can horizontally scale your services to any number. All requests will
eventually reach the same database.

There are various ways to protect it: caching I already mentioned (depends on your use case), duplicate some info on other servers to serve some queries as you mention, [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (depends on your use case), use a relational vs non-relational (depends on your use case again), etc.

Note though that when you distribute data like that, the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) starts to apply. Be aware of that as you might need to compromise between consistency and availability.

> It would scale better as we can add more machines to run the REST services;

Yes, the REST service will scale, but as I mentioned above, if you don't protect the database, that can easily become a bottleneck.

> It is possible to use HTTPS with compression for security and bandwidth saving reasons;

Yes, as well as other things... maybe you want authentication/authorization later, etc.

> It is possible to make some centralized changes on business entities without redeploying the 2000+ machines;

Yes, but up to a certain extent and not all kind of changes. If you make a breaking change you will need to update the clients too. So think about a strategy to update the clients to the latest version or if you allow older clients to still work and use the application.

> It integrates better with other systems (just point it to the REST service).

Yes, but that means clients for your service that maybe you can't control.

If you do a breaking change and you have a good strategy to update your 2000+ JavaFX clients then no problem. But if other clients exist and you don't have
control over them, you might need to implement versioning on the REST service and support more than one version until everyone can update to the latest.

Like I said, it depends on what you are trying to do. Overall, yours is a good idea. But be aware that stuff will not come for free just because you stick a REST service in front of a database.

Just my 2 cents!

Comment: Good reply. I only wanted to highlight to Thiago that it's worth considering versioning in a RESTful API as soon as possible. You may not need to do it at the start but you should be aware of it and be prepared.